# Python class not recognizing list

Tags: python, list, class

I am attempting to build one of my first classes ever and after checking some documentation and other StackOverflow questions I cannot figure out why I am getting `NameError: name 'executed_trades' is not defined` in the code listed below:

```py
class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.executed_trades = []

    def add_position(self, execution):
        if execution not in executed_trades:
            executed_trades.append(execution)
```

Does it not belong under `__init__()`? Is there something different about declaration in classes I am missing? It feels like a relatively simple error but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `self` in `add_position` method when you refer to `executed_trades`:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.executed_trades = []

    def add_position(self, execution):
        if execution not in self.executed_trades:
            self.executed_trades.append(execution)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One of those things that is bash-you-over-the-head simple in hindsight. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access `executed_trades`, use `self.executed_trades` as it's an attribute of your class.